# Play forms: how to fill a repeated field?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a form with a repeated field:

```scala
case class MyForm(topics: List[Int])
val myForm: Form[MyForm] = Form(
  mapping(
    "topics" -> list(number)
  )(MyForm.apply _)(MyForm.unapply _)
)
```

And the corresponding view:

```scala
@form(...) {
  <h2>Topics of interest:</h2>
  @for(Topic(id, name, _) <- Topics.all) {
    @checkbox(
      bidForm(s"topics[$id]"),
      '_label -> (name + ":").capitalize,
      'value -> id.toString)
  }
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
}
```

So far so good, if there is an error in the field and I re-render it passing `myForm.bindFromRequest`.

I would like to pre fill the form with data from my database. With other types of fields (`number`, `text`, `option()` and so on) I am able to populate an `existingMyForm` with something like this:

```scala
val existingMyForm = myForm.fill(MyForm(
  // Queries the database and return a list of case classes with field id: Int
  Topics.of(member).map(_.id)
))
```

However with `list` this approach fails and I have to manually do the mapping:

```scala
val existingMyForm = myForm.bind(
  Topics.of(member).map(t => ("topics[%s]".format(t.id), t.id.toString)).toMap
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have the same problem!
Did you fixed it ? if yes, how ?

Comment: Nop, I'm still using the same [hack](https://github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/SlickChair/blob/master/app/controllers/Submitting.scala#L70) :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to explicitly pass a List[Int] to the MyForm constructor, i.e.

```
val existingMyForm = myForm.fill(MyForm(
    Topics.of(member).map(_.id).toList
))
```

EDIT - Here is my basic implementation which worked for Play 2.1.1 Scala:

```
case class MyForm(topics: List[Int])
case class Topic(id: Int)
val myForm: Form[MyForm] = Form(
  mapping("topics" -> list(number))(MyForm.apply _)(MyForm.unapply _)
)

val topicList:List[Topic] = List(Topic(1), Topic(2), Topic(3))

def test = Action { implicit req =>
  val existingMyForm = myForm.fill(MyForm(
    topicList.map(_.id)
  ))
  Ok(views.html.test(existingMyForm))
}
```

Comment: [Topics.of](https://github.com/SlickChair/SlickChair/blob/master/app/models/entities/Topics.scala#L38) returns a List[Topic] and Topic has a id: Int field, so this .toList on a List[Int] will not change anything.

Comment: You're right.  Please see my edit, the only thing I can think of is that Topics.of doesn't return a list.  Would it be possible to see how Topics.of is implemented?

Comment: My previous comment has a link to Topics.of implementation.

Comment: I've checked out your project and replaced my contrived list with a call to Topics.of().  Not seeing any errors.  Have you verified that even this smaller example fails?  I noticed that your hack is used with larger, more complicated forms.